# Implementing foreign key from two different tables

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables and from first table I want to send data column `transId` into second table column `refId`, and the same from third table I want to send data column `transId` into second table column `refId` with relation of both first and third table. How is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by 'send'? Do you mean when a record is inserted into table1, it's transid is immediately inserted into another table? You need to define 'send'

Comment: You can create Multiple Foreign Key On Same Column

Comment: but each of those would require the value to exist.

Comment: You want to **link** those tables via a FK-PK relationship - you don't *send data* from one table to another.....

Answer (score 0):

We can create Multiple Foreign Key On Same Column, but each of those would require the value to exist.

```
Eg: 
Table1(1,2,3)
Table2(3,4)
```

You can insert the value `3` to the `table3` column that have the foreign key relation to both `table1` and `table2`(value `3` exists in both `table1` and `table2`), but you can't insert any other values.

There is one more method to solve this, you can use an `User Defined Function` inside a `Check constraint` of `table3` column to check the value exists or not in the `table1` and `table2`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send data from table to other. you only need to make reference from foreign_key_column (refId) to Primary_key_column (transId).

As example:
Using SQL Server

```
// foreign key in second table
CREATE TABLE Table2
(
refId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table1(transId)
)
// foreign key in third table
CREATE TABLE Table3
(
refId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table1(transId)
)
```

[helped Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Seems Table2 is the master table containing column transId which references to two tables table 1 and table 2.You need to go with the creation of foreign key in table 2 and table 3 for column transId.You can use below syntax for creating relationship among tables:

```
--foreign key in First table
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
 refId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table2(transId)
 )
-- foreign key in third table
 CREATE TABLE Table3
 (
 refId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Table2(transId)
 )
```